# The method allBoolean(Boolean[]) is undefined for the type Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods, boolean

I need for a program I´m writing, a method that allows me to check any array if its entirely made of true, false or a mix of both. I´ve come up with the code down here but apparently `The method allBoolean(Boolean[]) is undefined for the type Arrays`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myClass a = new myClass();
        Arrays.allBoolean(examplearray1);
    }
    public static Boolean[] examplearray1 = {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true};
    public static Boolean[] examplearray2 = {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true};
    public static Boolean[] examplearray3 = {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true};

public void allBoolean(Boolean[] a) {
    if (Arrays.asList(a).contains(false)) {
    if (Arrays.asList(a).contains(true)){
        System.out.println("mixed");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("all false");
    }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("all true");
    }
}
```

I really can´t figure out whats wrong. Probably just some stupid distarction error I made while writing the code, but if anyone knows why it sends me an error message, Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`allBoolean()` is a method of your class, not of `Arrays`. `Arrays.allBoolean(examplearray1);` should probably be `a.allBoolean(examplearray1);` since you previously do `myClass a = new myClass();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(yourValue)
```

**this doesn't work for arrays of primitives**

use stream instead, then you don't need this if-else logic that really hard to follow

```
boolean test = Stream.of(a).anyMatch(e->e == true);
boolean test1= Stream.of(a).anyMatch(e->e == false);
```